# import a file name directly in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

It is legit to import a file directly in ES6 according to here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing any
>   bindings.
>
> ```
> import "my-module";
> ```

I do not understand the sentence. So I created a minimal example to try to understand it.

```
//a.js
function print1()
{
  console.log("export print1 is working");
}

//b.js
import "/import/tags";
print1();
```

When I ran "b.js", I got an error:

> print1 is not defined

Thanks

Derek

Comment: you need add keyword `export` before `print1` in `a.js`, so that it would be exposed/exported outside, which then your can import as a module. `import { print1} from "/a.js"`

Comment: @OriDrori Agreed.  I will close the topic.